# Angualrjs get value from factory when scope change

Tags: angularjs, factory, watch

I have a factory use to get data with a condition. what I want is when the condition change the factory also need to update.

```
$scope.format=1;    
homefact.get_download_format($scope.format).then(function (response) {
        $scope.download = response;
  });

//watch scople format
  $scope.$watch("format", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if ($scope.format === 1) {
         //recall the get_donwload_format here with new value

        } else {
            //recall the get_donwload_format here with new value
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: at both the places you want  *//recall the get_donwload_format here with new value..*, then why if/else ?

Comment: haha got it. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the service around a function and call it inside the watch function

```
$scope.format=1;    
callDownload($scope.format);

function callDownload(newValue){
 homefact.get_download_format(newValue).then(function (response) {
    $scope.download = response;
 });
}

$scope.$watch("format", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if ($scope.format === 1) {
         callDownload(newValue)

        } else {
            //recall the get_donwload_format here with new value
        }
});
```

Comment: @Vuong Tran nice. make sure to check as answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't see use of `if/else`, since you want to call the service method with the `newValue` whenever `$scope.format` changes.

So it can be done like:

```
  $scope.format=1;    
  homefact.get_download_format($scope.format).then(function (response) {
        $scope.download = response;
   });

  //watch scople format
  $scope.$watch("format", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue != oldValue && newValue) {
      homefact.get_download_format(newValue).then(function (response) {
           $scope.download = response;
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your answer is good but we need to copy and pasted the whole get_downlaod_format function. Not a good idea.

Comment: IMO it's just a call and used at one point, so that's ok.. but if used at multiple places then wrap it in another function.